# display xml and xslt in a browser

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have 2 files, file.xml and file.xsl that I have made. I am looking for how to see the result in a browser. From my research I have understood that only IE got an xml parser and that for the others browser I need a servor script. 
I have also put these lines at the top of my xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Employe.xsl"?>
```

and these lignes at the top of my xsl file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

However, even when i'm using IE (11) I only have the text without any style that I have put. 
I wanted to display the elemnts in a table but there isn't any.

I am giving you my code for the table if there is any mistakes I haven't found, but normaly it is ok.

Here is the xsl code :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>

    <h2>List of Workers</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th rowspan=3> ID </th>
            <th colspan=5> Basic Information </th>
            <th rowspan=3> Picture </th>
            <th colspan=2> Skills enable </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan=2> Name </td>
            <td colspan=3> Address </td>
            <td rowspan=2> Phone Number </td>
            <td rowspan=2> Skill 1 </td>
            <td rowspan=2> Skill 2 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Number </td>
            <td> Street </td>
            <td> Town </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="List_Of_Employe/Employe">
        <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Address/Number"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Address/Street"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Address/Town"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Phone_Number"/><td/>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Photo"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Skills_Enable/Skill_1"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Skills_Enable/Skill_2"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and here is my xml code :

```
<List_Of_Employe>



    <Employe>

        <ID> 1235 </ID>

        <Basic_Information>

            <Name> James Bond</Name>

            <Address>
                <Number > 05 </Number>
                <Street> Queen's street </Street>
                <Town> London </Town>
            </Address>

            <Phone_Number> 07876543210 </Phone_Number>

        </Basic_Information>

        <Photo> James.png </Photo>

        <Skills_Enable>
            <Skill_1> XML </Skill_1>
            <Skill_2> C# </Skill_2>
        </Skills_Enable>

    </Employe>

    <Employe>

        <ID> 1236 </ID>

        <Basic_Information>

            <Name> Sherlock Holmes </Name>

            <Address>
                <Number > 100 </Number>
                <Street> Prince's street </Street>
                <Town> London </Town>
            </Address>

            <Phone_Number> 07765432100 </Phone_Number>

        </Basic_Information>

        <Photo> Sherlock.png </Photo>

        <Skills_Enable>
            <Skill_1> JavaScript </Skill_1>
            <Skill_2> Python </Skill_2>
        </Skills_Enable>

    </Employe>


 </List_Of_Employe>
```

Hoping you will be able to help me

Mayeul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stylesheet needs some improvement, but you're not far off a solution. It's not a beautiful solution, but it successfully transforms your input XML. (A better solution would have used several templates, not a huge one with several `for-each` statements).

**Clearing up a few things**

You say:

> From my research I have understood that only IE got an xml parser and that for the others browser I need a servor script

No, that's not true. Every major browser has a decent XML parser. You do not need any server-side code to parse XML. Likewise, every major browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari) ships with an XSLT processor, though only supporting XSLT 1.0.

> However, even when i'm using IE (11) I only have the text without any style that I have put.

Getting nothing but all textual content from the input XML as the result of a transformation usually means: none of your templates could match the input elements. None of your code was applied, and the default action is taken: invoking the built-in templates, that only output all text nodes.

It's unclear to me why no templates should apply in your case, let me know whether the stylesheet I suggest below changes the output.

**Stylesheet**

I have made the following changes to your stylesheet:

- There was a stray `<td/>` that should be `</td>`, because it ends a `td` element.
- Added quotes to all attribute values. Attribute values absolutely need to be in quotes (`"..."`), since the XSLT code must itself be well-formed XML.

An HTML parser can deal with a lot of errors (e.g. unquoted attribute values), but XML parsers are very strict on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>

    <h2>List of Workers</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th rowspan="3"> ID </th>
            <th colspan="5"> Basic Information </th>
            <th rowspan="3"> Picture </th>
            <th colspan="2"> Skills enable </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"> Name </td>
            <td colspan="3"> Address </td>
            <td rowspan="2"> Phone Number </td>
            <td rowspan="2"> Skill 1 </td>
            <td rowspan="2"> Skill 2 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Number </td>
            <td> Street </td>
            <td> Town </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="List_Of_Employe/Employe">
        <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Address/Number"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Address/Street"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Address/Town"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Phone_Number"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Photo"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Skills_Enable/Skill_1"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Skills_Enable/Skill_2"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also consider adding the following line to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
```

To make it explicit that you'd like to output HTML.

**XHTML Output**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>List of Workers</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th rowspan="3"> ID </th>
            <th colspan="5"> Basic Information </th>
            <th rowspan="3"> Picture </th>
            <th colspan="2"> Skills enable </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"> Name </td>
            <td colspan="3"> Address </td>
            <td rowspan="2"> Phone Number </td>
            <td rowspan="2"> Skill 1 </td>
            <td rowspan="2"> Skill 2 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> Number </td>
            <td> Street </td>
            <td> Town </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> 1235 </td>
            <td> James Bond</td>
            <td> 05 </td>
            <td> Queen's street </td>
            <td> London </td>
            <td> 07876543210 </td>
            <td> James.png </td>
            <td> XML </td>
            <td> C# </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> 1236 </td>
            <td> Sherlock Holmes </td>
            <td> 100 </td>
            <td> Prince's street </td>
            <td> London </td>
            <td> 07765432100 </td>
            <td> Sherlock.png </td>
            <td> JavaScript </td>
            <td> Python </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Rendered Output**

I do not have IE to try it out there, but Firefox renders the HTML output to:

> [image]

Finally, let me be nit-picking for a brief moment, it really should read "Employee", not "Employe".

Comment: Have you modified the code ? The result you got is what I want to obtain but it is not working, even is mozilla firefox (I just tried), it says that my xml isn't well formed but target the error in th xsl file

Comment: @Mayeulsgc Yes, I have modified the code. Make sure you try with _exactly the code I am showing_ (just copy all of it), with _exactly the input XML you are showing_. The XML you are showing is definitely well-formed, as is my XLST stylesheet. Did you read through all what I wrote?

Comment: Ok it works thank you 
I have spent so much time for a simple quote error -_-